# How can I name my matrix using dimnames()?

Tags: r

Is there a way I can name my matrix rows and columns using dim names()? With the code below it just creates a new column called dimnames and displaying "character,4".

```
    rbind(c(1, 0, 1, 1),c(0, 1, 1, 0),c(1, 1, 0, 1),c(1, 0, 1, 0),dimnames = list(c("Kormo", "Vasco", "Bosco", "Ivo"), c("Kormo", "Vasco", "Bosco", "Ivo")))
```

Comment: You were almost correct. i.e. just `rbind` the vectors (`rbind` doesn't have `dimnames` argument.  It is there in `matrix`) and create a matrix.  Then assign the `dimnames` on the object created.  It should be `m1 <- rbind(c(1, 0, 1, 1),c(0, 1, 1, 0),c(1, 1, 0, 1),c(1, 0, 1, 0));dimnames(m1) <- list(c("Kormo", "Vasco", "Bosco", "Ivo"), c("Kormo", "Vasco", "Bosco", "Ivo"))`

Comment: `structure(rbind(c(1, 0, 1, 1),c(0, 1, 1, 0),c(1, 1, 0, 1),c(1, 0, 1, 0)),dimnames = list(c("Kormo", "Vasco", "Bosco", "Ivo"), c("Kormo", "Vasco", "Bosco", "Ivo")))`